# the probability for a stochastic process $\mathbb{P}(\text{sup}_{0\leq t\leq2}X_t\geq1)$, where $X_t = \int _0^t\frac{dW_s}{\sqrt{1+s}}$

Tags: stochastic-calculus

$X_t = \int _0^t\frac{dW_s}{\sqrt{1+s}}$, the probability $\mathbb{P}(\text{sup}_{0\leq t\leq2}X_t\geq1)$

Comment: What is the distribution of an Ito integral? Its moments?

Comment: Do you just want to estimate the probability or do you want to compute it explicitly?

Comment: to compute the exact probability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $ X_t=\int_0^t\frac{dW_s}{\sqrt{1+s}} $, then $ \{X_t,t\ge 0\} $ is a continuous Gaussian process with independent increments, 
and $ \mathsf{E}[X_t]=0$, $ \mathsf{E}[X_t^2]=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{ds}{1+s}=\log(1+t)  $. 
Meanwhile, $ \{W_{\log(1+t)},t\ge 0\} $ is also a continuous Gaussian process with independent increments, 
and $ \mathsf{E}[W_{\log(1+t)}]=0$, $ \mathsf{E}[W_{\log(1+t)}^2]=\log(1+t)$ too. Hence  $ \{X_t,t\ge 0\} $ and $ \{W_{\log(1+t)},t\ge 0\} $ are same distributed.
Furthermore,
\begin{align*}
&\mathsf{P}\left(\sup_{0\le t \le 2}X_t \ge 2\right)
=\mathsf{P}\left(\sup_{0\le t \le 2}W_{\log(1+t)} \ge 2\right)\\
&\quad =\mathsf{P}\left(\sup_{0\le s \le \log3}W_{s} \ge 2\right)
=2\mathsf{P}(W(\log3)\ge 2) \qquad \text{by reflection principle}\\
&\quad = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi\log3}}\int_{2}^{\infty}e^{-u^2/(2\log3)}\,\mathrm{d}u.
\end{align*}